# Prove that $\chi$ is Riemann integrable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

Let $R=[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$, consider the set $D=${$(x,y); x^2+y^2 \leq1$}.

$\chi_{D}$ is Riemann integrable in R.

$\chi_{D}=$$  \left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{l}
     1 \text{ if } (x,y)\in D \\
     0 \text{ if } (x,y)\notin D \\
  \end{array}
  \right.$

I can't find the way to do this exercise. I supposed that I need to prove that this limit is $0$: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sum_{R_{jk}} area R_{jk}=0$. But I do not know if it is ok

Comment: It is L-integrable because $D$ is measurable, and since it is bounded and continuous a.e., it is R-integrable.

Comment: Not knowing what $R_{jk}$ is even supposed to be, I cannot say whether or not your limit is either true or useful. The only possibility that comes to my mind for it would converge to $2\pi$, not $0$.